# how to write complex matrix into file?

Tags: printing, matlab

i am having a problem with writing a complex matrix into a text file. The matrix looks ok in matlab but in text file it is strange. The sign of the imaginary part is not correctly printed.

In MATLAB:
[image]

In Notepad:
[image]

here is the code for writing:

```
for i=1:18550
       writematrix((data_copy(i,:)),'OP1_komega_3227Hz_rot_scaled_f.txt','Delimiter','tab','WriteMode','append');
end
```

and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SleXfygFTZMoFJEAK8c1JPAE5DXV2x7K/view?usp=sharing) you can find the matrix.

Comment: Not my arrea, but that looks like a delimiter.

Comment: Might be a bug, see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/494870-error-while-using-writematrix-to-save-complex-values-in-a-txt (found by a google search for "matlab writematrix complex")

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a bug, but you can convert your matrix to string then write it using writematrix, suppose you want to write matrix A in text file:

```
>> A=(rand(5,3)-0.5)+(rand(5,3)-0.5)*i

A =

  -0.0495 + 0.3687i   0.3258 - 0.0686i  -0.3933 - 0.3639i
  -0.4162 - 0.4156i   0.0383 + 0.4106i   0.4619 + 0.3693i
  -0.2710 - 0.1002i   0.4961 - 0.3182i  -0.4954 + 0.0797i
   0.4133 - 0.2401i  -0.4218 - 0.2362i   0.2749 + 0.0499i
  -0.3476 + 0.3001i  -0.0573 - 0.3545i   0.3173 - 0.3550i

>> writematrix(string(A))
```

result:

```
-0.049458+0.36869i,0.32582-0.068586i,-0.39335-0.36393i
-0.41618-0.41556i,0.038342+0.41065i,0.4619+0.36929i
-0.27102-0.10022i,0.49613-0.31815i,-0.49537+0.079705i
0.41334-0.24013i,-0.42182-0.2362i,0.27491+0.04986i
-0.34762+0.30007i,-0.057322-0.35446i,0.3173-0.35505i
```